# Loop not working with assosiative array Php

Tags: php, arrays

Can i make multidimensionalarrry to assosiative array, Right now i am getting following result

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [minimum_marks] => 55
            [maximum_marks] => 65
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [minimum_marks] => 44
            [maximum_marks] => 70
         }
)
```

I just want to put all values in single, i want result like following array

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [minimum_marks] => 55
    [maximum_marks] => 65
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [minimum_marks] => 44
    [maximum_marks] => 70
)
```

Here is my code,My code not showing only one record with loop (code should showing all minimum_marks and maximum_marks), where i am wrong ?

$result = $query->result_array();

```
$simpleArray = [];
foreach ($result as $skuArray) {
  $simpleArray['minimum_marks'] = $skuArray['minimum_marks'];
  $simpleArray['maximum_marks'] = $skuArray['maximum_marks'];
}

print_R($simpleArray);
```

Comment: You can not have duplicate keys in an array. I think you are overwriting them. Looking at the data, don't you already have what you are looking for?

Comment: Why do you need like this? Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: have you tried [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)? Or you could do `$simpleArray['minimum_marks'][] = $skuArray['minimum_marks'];`

Comment: Could you explain why do you want to convert your array like this. If you elaborate a bit more, we can guide you the better way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are you expecting this output. But my suggestion, if you want it really?

```
$simpleArray = [];
foreach ($result as $skuArray) {
  $simpleArray['minimum_marks'] = $skuArray['minimum_marks'];
  $simpleArray['maximum_marks'] = $skuArray['maximum_marks'];
  print_R($simpleArray);
}
```

Print the value inside loop, so it wont push and it wont create multiple array. every time, it will overwrite. But please be sure, finally you get last array value only on the simpleArray. Hope you understood!

Let me explain with example. If you want to display the marks in table, I will suggest you to return directly like below instead of creating variable and retrieving it again.

```
echo '<table>
<tr><th>Min Marks</th><th>Max Marks</th></tr>';
foreach ($result as $skuArray) {
  $minMarks = $skuArray['minimum_marks'];
  $maxMarks = $skuArray['maximum_marks'];
  echo '<tr><td>'.$minMarks.'</td><td>'.$minMarks.'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want.

If you want to get your array in two different variables you can try this:

Use dynamic variables, the name of the variable is dynamically generated in your loop.

```
foreach($result as $key => $_array){
   //$key is your inder of you multidimensional
   $name_variable = '_array_number_'.$key; //Name of the variable
   $$name_variable = $_array; //Instanciate dynamic variable
}

//You got now this two array
print_r($_array_number_0); 
print_r($_array_number_1);
```

But please be more precise next time with what you expect and why you need this.

By the way, what happened to your code is that in the first loop you instanciate 'minimum_marks' and 'maximum_marks' in $_simple_array.

But in your second loop you **overwrite** the value of 'minimum_marks' and 'maximum_marks'.